# Python - is packing everything in a for loop into a function a good idea?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization

This question is not about opinion, it's about understanding of some mechanisms of Python.

Let's take the following code (not real one, just a dummy code):

```
for i in range(1000):
   x = 10 + i*10
   y = some_calculations(x)
   z = send_data_to_db(y)
```

Does it make sense in terms of performance to pack the actions I do with x, y and z into one function? Like this:

```
def handle_everything(a):
   x = 10 + a*10
   y = some_calculations(x)
   z = send_data_to_db(y)
   return z 

for i in range(1000):
   z = handle_everything(i)
```

The reason I am asking is the following. In this [article](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) the author describes the mechanisms of importing a module in Python.

- a module object is a dictionary
- new functions and classes won’t appear in the module’s namespace until the def (or class) statement has been executed.

Based on this, I came to conclusion, that for functions that are going to be reused, Python doesn't make compilation again. And therefore I thought, that maybe it makes sense to pack all the actions inside of a loop into functions / one function. After I implemented this modification, my measurements showed, that the execution time wasn't affected much.

Please let me know, if understood something wrong.

Comment: The question is, are _you_ going to reuse the function after this.

Comment: only inside the loop. so that it is being reused in every iteration.

Comment: Sure, it is being "reused" every iteration, but that is not the right implication behind the word. Here, we mean: "do you need to type these 3 lines in more than one place inside your program? If yes, use a function".

Comment: Since you are asking about performance, let me remind you that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). What you are doing here, asking this particular question, is definitely a case of premature optimization ;)

Comment: @vlad.rad Is optimization the goal here? Because if it is I would say that this seems like a premature optimization which don't forget _" is the root of all evil"_ ;)

Comment: Keep in mind, though, there *is* a significant cost (more so than in other compiled languages) to calling a user-defined function in Python. It *may* be premature to worry about that overhead, but it is definitely something to be aware of.

Comment: This is not an issue of Python implementation or even a `for` loop.  This is system design and deployment, dependent on how you will invoke the code within one application, and whether you'll use it again (**reuse**) in future applications.

Comment: @zvone Damn, that is scary... even the use of ";)" is similar lol

Comment: @scharette yes ;)

Comment: @chepner Can you elaborate on this a bit. I'm curious.

Comment: @scharette The reason why I am worrying about performance here, is that the execution time really matters in my case - I have a strict limit on it.

Comment: So guys actually the question is about understanding of Python mechanisms. @chepner says, that there is a significant cost to call user-defined function in Python. So as fas as I understand, there is no general rule like "pack the most of the code into functions" or something like that, right?

Comment: @vlad.rad But did you measure the performance? The problem with this kind of premature optimization is that you might already be 10000 time faster than needed or 10000 times slower than needed and in both cases this kind of optimization is useless. Measure performance, if it is too slow, profile it, then optimize the slowest part of it.

Comment: Also, you can look for other ways to refactor your code than simply wrapping things in functions. For example, you don't need `x = 10 + i * 10` in this loop; you want to iterate over 1000 multiples of 10 starting with 10, so do that: `for i in islice(count(10, 10), 1000):`

Comment: @zvone yes I measured it, and it didn't become better after my "optimization". Then I understood that there is probably something I am missing about how Python calls user-defined functions.

Comment: @chepner good point! OP could also use `range(10, 10010, 10)` and be able to take out the entire `x=` line.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when questioning the python ideals I find it best to open an interactive session and run:

```
>>>import this
```

Which prints (and comes standard with python)

```
"""
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
"""
```

Where I think the most applicable parts for your question are:

- `Simple is better than complex.` Not using a function is probably simpler, in that you won't need to scroll back and forth through your program, and your code is a couple lines shorter.
- `Readability counts.` This would depend on the way the rest of your script is set up. If your `for` loop will get a lot more added, then a function would probably make it a lot easier to read. Typically a `main()` function does nothing more than call functions I've defined in my scripts -> my main program flow is very readable.

You should note "Achieve the best execution time" is not mentioned. This should be (mostly) an afterthought once you have a working script. At that point you can time how long your program spends in each function and focus on optimizing the worst time losses! To optimize for speed before your script is done will not be worth the hassle in 95% of use cases. This stems from the fact you don't know where you are losing time! Say one part of your script takes 1 second to execute, and another takes 100 seconds. If you try to optimize without a working script you may try to speed up the thing that already only takes 1 second...Say you cut 50% time, well who cares about .5 seconds. The same 50% speed increase in the other section of your code would save you 50 seconds though!!! This is why you need to target your optimization on the slowest segments first, which you can't identify until your script is finished anyways...